# Turning CNF into DNF

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, conjunctive-normal-form, disjunctive-normal-form

I have a formula

$(L\Leftrightarrow (A\vee J))$

and I am to turn it into DNF and CNF. When I use de Morgan rules and so on, the formula looks like

$(L\Rightarrow (A\vee J))\wedge ((A\vee J)\Rightarrow L)$

$(\lnot L\vee (A\vee J))\wedge ((\lnot A\wedge \lnot J)\vee L)$

the CNF is pretty easy its

$(\lnot L \vee A\vee J)\wedge (L\vee \lnot A)\wedge (L\vee \lnot J)$

But how can I make DNF out of this formula?

Comment: Do you mean "KNF" (as in the title) or "CNF" (Conjunctive Normal Form, as in the text)?

Comment: sorry its CNF ( but in my national language its KNF :) )

Comment: Do a Karnaugh map.  Collect fullest lines/squares first.

Comment: See http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/don/courses/math1904/lect11.pdf

Comment: i have tried it with Karnaugh maps , but didnt get the right result , could you elaborate? I havent found anything usefull in that pdf

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to calculate a DNF logically equivalent to the formula $L \Leftrightarrow (A \lor J)$ is to look at its truth table and "build" the formula corresponding to the "disjunction" of the rows for which $L \Leftrightarrow (A \lor J)$ is true.

$\begin{array}{ccccc}
A & J & L & A \lor J & L \Leftrightarrow (A \lor J) \\
\mathtt{t} & \mathtt{t} & \mathtt{t} & \mathtt{t} & \mathtt{t} \\
\mathtt{t} & \mathtt{t} & \mathtt{f} & \mathtt{t} & \mathtt{f} \\
\mathtt{t} & \mathtt{f} & \mathtt{t} & \mathtt{t} & \mathtt{t} \\
\mathtt{t} & \mathtt{f} & \mathtt{f} & \mathtt{t} & \mathtt{f} \\
\mathtt{f} & \mathtt{t} & \mathtt{t} & \mathtt{t} & \mathtt{t} \\
\mathtt{f} & \mathtt{t} & \mathtt{f} & \mathtt{t} & \mathtt{f} \\
\mathtt{f} & \mathtt{f} & \mathtt{t} & \mathtt{f} & \mathtt{f} \\
\mathtt{f} & \mathtt{f} & \mathtt{f} & \mathtt{f} & \mathtt{t} \\
\end{array}$

The formula $L \Leftrightarrow (A \lor J)$ is true at rows 1 (which corresponds to the formula $A \land J \land L$), row 3 (which corresponds to the formula $A \land \lnot J \land L$), row 5 (which corresponds to the formula $\lnot A \land J \land L$), and row 8 (which corresponds to the formula $\lnot A \land \lnot J \land \lnot L$). Hence, a DNF logically equivalent to $L \Leftrightarrow (A \lor J)$ is 
\begin{equation*}
(A \land J \land L) \lor (A \land \lnot J \land L) \lor (\lnot A \land J \land L) \lor (\lnot A \land \lnot J \land \lnot L).
\end{equation*}